# How to create a custom session store

Tags: c#, owin

I am implementing owin middleware,where i need to store the session in database.
Consider this example-

```
var options = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
                CookieName = "ChatCookies",
                LoginPath = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.LoginPath,
                LogoutPath = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.LogoutPath,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                SessionStore = 
            };
```

Here there is session store option and i want to implement it, so i am not able to figure it ,how to do it. Please help me to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of a class that implements `IAuthenticationSessionStore`. The interface itself is quite simple:

```
public interface IAuthenticationSessionStore
{
    Task RemoveAsync(string key);
    Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket);
    Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key);
    Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket);
}
```

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/vibronet/90d4646c273930ff12d4) an example of the implementation of that interface. Then, simply pass your instance in:

```
public class CustomAuthenticationSessionStore : IAuthenticationSessionStore {
    // Your implementation depending on use case goes here.

    public Task RemoveAsync(string key) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task RenewAsync(string key, AuthenticationTicket ticket) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<AuthenticationTicket> RetrieveAsync(string key) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<string> StoreAsync(AuthenticationTicket ticket) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

var options = new CookieAuthenticationOptions() {
    AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
    CookieName = "ChatCookies",
    LoginPath = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.LoginPath,
    LogoutPath = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.LogoutPath,
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    SessionStore = new CustomAuthenticationSessionStore()
};
```

Comment: I was looking to the github url,but unable to figure out how to set up the cookieauthenticationstore, because the constructor is accepting ticketdataformat object.

Comment: I have the same question. The documentation says: "- An optional container in which to store the identity across requests..." .-Across request-, but always across requests  it's imposible store identity because once the user has been authenticated, only calls `RetrieveAsync`. How can store identity across request if always `RetrieveAsync` is called? I need `RenewAsync` or `StoreAsync` calls for each request, It is not like this?

Comment: To use the example in the gist, you need to create a TicketDataFormat instance. You can create it like this (when you set the cookie options): 
var dataProtector = app.CreateDataProtector(typeof(NaiveEFAuthSessionStore).FullName, "MyEntropy", "v1");
var sessionStore = new NaiveEFAuthSessionStore (new TicketDataFormat(dataProtector));